# Angularjs controller without state. How to add dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next template:

```
<body>
    <div id="page_wrapper">
        <div id="head_content"
             data-ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"
             data-ng-include="'header/header.tpl.html'">
        </div>

        <div id="main_content" data-ui-view="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

From the server Angulat gets config by AJAX request.
The "main" View is managed by controllers which depend on ui-router by nested states and resolve property of $routeProvider.

But " data-ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" " is used to display a common header for all states and it uses the same config from the server.

At this moment there are 2 request to the server for this config:
1. one for ui-router states for almost all controllers.
2. and a separate for **HeaderCtrl**

Is there something similar to **resolve: {}** property for such standalone controllers in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, since the `HeaderCtrl` nested into some `MainController`, his scope protptypically inherit scope of the `MainController` and you can access `$scope.configuration` property of parent from any children controllers.
And also, you can explicitely notify all chidlren about state change propagating event downward with `$scope.$emit` and pass your config object as parameter.